# django Signals launched twice when action is done in admin

Tags: python, django, signals, admin

I've a simple signals which is launch when the object is deleted

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Operation, dispatch_uid="delete_operation")
def delete_operation(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Track balance operations for delete
    instance.user.balance = instance.user.balance - int(instance.amount) # Note the "-"
    instance.user.save()
```

The problem is that when I delete the object into the admin, the signals is launch twice and false my balance. I would like to avoid the 2 times trigger. I searched on stackoverflow and tried several solutions but still not working.

Here is how I import the signals :

## apps.py

```
class CommonConfig(AppConfig):
name = 'sl.common'

def ready(self):
    import sl.common.signals
```

If anyone has ideas it's welcome !!

Comment: Have you tried pre_delete?

Comment: Where does this code reside? How is it included in your application?

Comment: I didn't try pre_delete since we need post_delete. this code resides in the core app. first one is in common.signals. the lonely problem is that this code works but is launched twice in admin. so that's bad

Answer (score 0):

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Operation, dispatch_uid="delete_operation")
def delete_operation(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    if action[0:4] == 'post':
        # Track balance operations for delete
        instance.user.balance = instance.user.balance - int(instance.amount) # Note the "-"
        instance.user.save()
```

Each signal has two actions: pre and post - pre instance has fields before changes, post instance has fields after changes.

- pre_add and post_add
- pre_remove and post_remove